# How can I add parent and 2 level of child entity with updating 1 level of child in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have parent entity with has Child1 list. Child1 entity has Child2 entity list.
My aim is creating Parent and 2 level child(Child2) entities on datyabase with updating parentId s on Child1 entity. Let me give details.

```
Parent{

int ID;
List<Child1> child1;
.....
}

Child1{
int ID;
int parent_ID;
....
List<Child2> child2;

}

Child2{
int ID;
int child1_ID;

....

}
```

How can I achieve this operation by EF Core?

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to clarify what you intend to happen:

For instance, based on your description, if you have the current:

```
Parent: "Dad"
  Child1s (1)
  -> Child1: "Peter"
     Child2s (0)
```

and you want to add a new Parent "Mom", move "Peter" from "Dad" to "Mom", and add a new Child 2 "Jill" under "Peter"

```
Parent: "Dad"
  Child1s (0)
Parent: "Mom"
  Child1s: (1)
  -> Child1: "Peter"
     Child2s (1)
     -> Child2: "Jill"

using(var context = new FamilyDbContext())
{
    var parent1 = context.Parents.Single(x => x.Name == "Dad");
    var parent2 = new Parent {Name = "Mom"};
    var child = parent1.Child1s.Single(x => x.Name == "Peter");
    parent1.Children.Remove(child);
    parent2.Children.Add(child);
    child.Parent = parent2;
    var grandChild = new Child2{Name = "Jill", Child = child};
    child.Child2s.Add(grandChild);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Don't try and update "ParentID" or such on children, instead update the references in the case where you want to move entities between parents. EF will manage the FKs.

Edit: If Child1 exists without an optional parent, and you want to add a Child2 to it and associate it to a new Parent:

```
using(var context = new FamilyDbContext())
{
    var child = context.Child1s.Single(x => x.Name == "Peter");
    var parent = new Parent {Name = "Dad"};
    var grandChild = new Child2 { Name = "Jill", Child1 = child };
    child.Parent = parent;
    parent.Child1s.Add(child);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The thing to watch out for with entities and changing associations etc. is ensuring that all entities in question are associated to the same DbContext instance. Often you can find methods that accept entities as parameters then run into problems as you try to add entities under a new DbContext and associate the entities that were passed in as parameters. These could be entities associated with a different context, or treated as new entities resulting in errors or duplicate data. Entities can be attached to a context, but this needs to be done carefully and only if you're sure the passed entity can be trusted and isn't already associated with the context.

So the above examples demonstrate loading and creating all affected entities in the scope of a DbContext. Something like this can cause problems:

```
public void MoveChild(Child1 child)
{
    using (var context = new FamilyContext())
    {
        var parent = new Parent {Name = "Dad"};
        var grandChild = new Child2 { Name = "Jill", Child1 = child };
        child.Parent = parent;
        parent.Child1s.Add(child);

        context.SaveChanges();        
    }
}
```

The reason is that "child" is not associated with our context. It may be associated with another context, or have been de-serialized making it effectively just a plain-ol` object, not a tracked entity.

To attach it you can do something like the following:

```
public void MoveChild(Child1 child)
{
    using (var context = new FamilyContext())
    {
        child = context.Child1s.Attach(child);
        var parent = new Parent {Name = "Dad"};
        var grandChild = new Child2 { Name = "Jill", Child1 = child };
        child.Parent = parent;
        parent.Child1s.Add(child);

        context.SaveChanges();        
    }
}
```

However code like this needs to be careful if for instance the DbContext is scoped module-level (rather than a `using` block) or you are operating against a collection of references that could be duplicated, or a nested structure of references. If you attach an entity that is already associated with the context, you will get an exception.

Comment: Great answer, you illustrate more complex situation compared to my question. If we think that:    
In first we have only
Child1: "Peter"
and create Dad and want to create grandchild(child2), what should we do?

Comment: I've expanded the answer to hopefully cover handling taking a Child and associating it to a new Parent + new Child2, plus some details to watch out for if Child1 was for instance passed into a method for this operation. (which is a fairly common pitfall people hit.)

Comment: Yes, It will help, I will apply. but Is there difference if I say
parent.Child1.add(child); instead of child.Parent = parent

Comment: Not really. Once you call `SaveChanges` the references for both would be brought up to sync. (parent.children & child.parent) I just set them explicitly in case there is any business logic added that accepts the parent/child as a parameter prior to SaveChanges being called. (Validation, logging, etc.) Where there may be a temporary discrepancy between parent and child references.

Comment: Thanks so much for comprehensive explanation.  Your key sentence is `Don't try and update "ParentID" or such on children, instead update the references in the case where you want to move entities between parents. EF will manage the FKs.`
You tell me all the logic of EF with one sentence. All rubbish documents doesn not explain this